# InDesign Margin Exporting To PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've been using InDesign for 6 years, and I've never had this issue. When I export a file to a pdf, the margin line is showing up on it. I can't seem to find anything online about this issue and have no idea why this would be happening. I didn't update or change anything with my version of InDesign. It started happening yesterday.

Edit: here's the picture. I had to mark out the identifying info, thus the weird white boxes. You can see the purple line - that's the margin guide that should be invisible when exporting. It doesn't show for any other format, just when I export to PDF.

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image showing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting during export:

> Visible Guides And Grids
>
> Exports margin guides, ruler guides, column guides, and baseline grids
>   currently visible in the document. Grids and guides export in the same
>   color used in the document.

https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/pdf-options.html

Examine that setting.

Comment: Ah HA! That's embarrassing...I have no idea how that got checked. I've never used that before. Thanks!

Comment: I never used it myself, but I suspect it is still a guide and may not actually print/can be disabled within the PDF viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I just enabled this option and got my margin added to the PDF. Just disable it and I think you should be fine.

[image: Disable this option]